# openafs operation timed out

Tags: osx-lion, openafs

I am running openAFS 1.6 on MacOS Lion. Sometimes when I try to access files in my AFS volume, I get an error message "Operation timed out". This does not happen all the time, but sometimes when I am on a wireless (slower connection) I get this error.

I cannot access any directory or file in the AFS after this, until I restart my computer. Trying to restart openAFS from System Preferences results in a terrible message asking me to restart my computer.

Is there some option that I could remove this Operation timed out and retry to connect to AFS without having to restart my computer? flush the cache or something?

Answer (score 2):

got the same issue, when a connection hick-up occurred. 
I was able to fix it using 
fs flushall